# Implicit invocation in google assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, voice

I tried to invoke the voice app in the following two ways - 1. Entering the exact invocation phrase as mentioned in actions on google - successful 2. Entered a similar invocation phrase (without mentioning the name of the app) - did not work

The app is in the alpha phase. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

For the best results, you should use the exact invocation phrases and not rely entirely on implicit invocation. As noted in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/discovery/implicit):

> Due to the evolving nature of the recommendation algorithm, Google cannot guarantee that your Action will be recommended via implicit invocation.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, it is mandatory to keep the Invocation name and action name **SAME**.
So I recommend you to follow the same.